# PLPGSQL function goes to infinite loop

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a plpgsql function that has to return the result in a new table. Below is the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vrg.VRGTest_Ver5(_tbl1_VRG regclass,_tbl2_urban regclass,_tbl3_postcodes regclass,t_name varchar(30))
RETURNS SETOF record AS

      $BODY$
      BEGIN

      EXECUTE format(

     ' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I.%I
(
    PostcodeName text,
    vrgid double precision,
    urban_gid integer,
    vrg_area double precision,
    urban_area double precision,
    weights double precision
 )',
    'vrg',
    ('' || t_name)
    );

       EXECUTE format  ('SELECT
             postcodes.name as PostcodeName,
             fishnet.fid as vrgid, 
             urban.gid as urban_gid, 
             st_area(fishnet.geom) as vrg_area,
             ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(urban.geom, fishnet.geom)) as urban_area,
             ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(urban.geom, fishnet.geom))/st_area(fishnet.geom) as weights
         FROM '   || _tbl1_VRG       ||  ' AS fishnet,'
              || _tbl2_urban     || ' as urban,'
              || _tbl3_postcodes || ' as postcodes
         WHERE 
             ST_INTERSECTS(urban.geom, fishnet.geom) and ST_INTERSECTS(fishnet.geom, postcodes.geom)')
         into t_name;
       END;   
       $BODY$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

How can I modify the code to write both create  and select statement in execute.format or is there any better way? I'm new to plpgsql.
When I run the function

```
  select vrg.VRGTest_Ver5( 'vrg.bb_sumatrapart_grid_1000m' ,'vrg.ghs_pop_indonesia_v2_reclass_poly_union_v2_projected','vrg.gfk_2016_id_5_digit_pcd_areas2013_projected',
                          'vrg.ResultTest')
```

it goes to infinite loop.

Comment: Firstly, it's not unique to plpgsql, you just use `CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS SELECT .....` type syntax to combine create and select. How do you know it goes into an infinite loop, as distinct from just takes a very long time? A good way to test would be simply to run the query outside of of plpgsql and use EXPLAIN to see that you are getting a sensible query plan before converting to plpgsql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the issue with the execution time (as @JohnPowellakaBarça pointed out), your function will still probably not work;

- `EXECUTE/SELECT ... INTO` is primarily meant to be used for single
  inserts (reference and more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22841127/6782776) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15560009/6782776))
- inserting `INTO` needs a defined variable to work, either in a `DECLARE` block or as an `OUT` paramter in the function definition; as it stands, the query above tries (and fails) to insert row after row into a **string** (`t_name` is a `VARCHAR`, that is, not more than a string; it´s not automatically considered to be e.g. a `RECORD`)
- you´re not returning anything; why not using `RETURNS VOID`

What you are trying to do can be achieved with a single `CREATE TABLE ... AS(..)` command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vrg.VRGTest_Ver5(_tbl1_VRG REGCLASS, _tbl2_urban REGCLASS, _tbl3_postcodes REGCLASS, t_name TEXT)
RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('
                CREATE TABLE %I.%I AS (
                    SELECT PostcodeName,
                           vrgid,
                           urban_gid,
                           vrg_area,
                           urban_area,
                           urban_area / vrg_area AS weights
                    FROM (
                        SELECT postcodes.name AS PostcodeName,
                               fishnet.fid AS vrgid, 
                               urban.gid AS urban_gid, 
                               ST_Area(fishnet.geom) AS vrg_area,
                               ST_Area(ST_Intersection(urban.geom, fishnet.geom)) AS urban_area
                        FROM %s AS urban
                        JOIN %s AS fishnet
                          ON ST_Intersects(urban.geom, fishnet.geom)
                        JOIN %s AS postcodes
                          ON ST_Intersects(fishnet.geom, postcodes.geom)
                    ) AS sub
                )',
                'vrg',
                t_name,
                _tbl2_urban,
                _tbl1_VRG,
                _tbl3_postcodes
            )
END;   
$BODY$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I added a subquery for a small performance boost; in your query, `ST_Area(fishnet.geom)` and `ST_Area(ST_Intersection(urban.geom, fishnet.geom))` are calcualted twice each for each match of the join, and on larger scales `ST_Intersection` becomes costly.
Make sure you have a spatial index on all geometry columns. Run `(VACUUM) ANALYZE` on all tables to refresh table statistics.